# Why reStructuredText plugin of VSCode raises error "Unknown directive type "glossary""?

Tags: visual-studio-code, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

reStructuredText plugin for VSCode is branded as a live preview for Sphinx documentation, but it raises many errors :

For `.. glossary::`

```
Unknown directive type "glossary".
```

For `.. toctree::`

```
Unknown directive type "toctree".
```

The official documentation does not cover such limitations. Is it an issue from my config ? Or from the plugin itself ?

Comment: Maybe you need to set "preview mode" to Sphinx: https://docs.restructuredtext.net/articles/preview#preview-mode-selection